# Running a While loop through several if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am currently learning Javascript and wanted to ask how can I run a while loop through several if statements so that I would get the 12 months displayed in a list, I think I am suppose to use a counter something like

```
while(monthName < 10){
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate it into my function:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = getMonth(0);
};

function getMonth(month) {
var monthName;
if (month == 0) {
    monthName = "January";
}
if (month == 1) {
    monthName = "February";
}
if (month == 2) {
    monthName = "March";
}
if (month == 3) {
    monthName = "April";
}
if (month == 4) {
    monthName = "May";
}
if (month == 5) {
    monthName = "June";
}
if (month == 6) {
    monthName = "July";
}
if (month == 7) {
    monthName = "August";
}
if (month == 8) {
    monthName = "September";
}
if (month == 9) {
    monthName = "October";
}  
if (month == 10) {
    monthName = "November";
}
if (month == 11) {
    monthName = "December";
}
return monthName;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/rUpsb/

I understand there are more effective ways of doing this, like using an Array, but asking for while loop/counter for educational purposes.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your function is craving usage of a `switch` statement.

Comment: You would have to refactor your code "a bit". Here is a good place for this[link to cool Page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You are basically duplicating the function of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var current = 0;
    var html = '';
    while(current < 12){
      html += getMonth(current++) + '<br />';        
    }
  document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = html;
};

function getMonth(month) {
var monthName;
if (month == 0) {
    monthName = "January";
}
if (month == 1) {
    monthName = "February";
}
if (month == 2) {
    monthName = "March";
}
if (month == 3) {
    monthName = "April";
}
if (month == 4) {
    monthName = "May";
}
if (month == 5) {
    monthName = "June";
}
if (month == 6) {
    monthName = "July";
}
if (month == 7) {
    monthName = "August";
}
if (month == 8) {
    monthName = "September";
}
if (month == 9) {
    monthName = "October";
}
if (month == 10) {
    monthName = "November";
}
if (month == 11) {
    monthName = "December";
}
return monthName;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rUpsb/1/

Comment: Answers the question, but it is not a good coding style(removed the vote down, because answered the actual question)

Comment: Jesus. and who puts you an expert for what is a good coding style. my god - he asks a question to learn - I am not trying to teach him all the aspects of good coding in my answer

Comment: Hi, thank you this is exactly what I was wondering, I know how to use an array for these purposes but was wondering how to use the while loop, thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an array:

```
var months = ['January','February','March'...];
```

Then you'll be able to return using the index:

```
for(var i=0, max=months.length; i<max; i++){

     // You could have an if statement in here to do any checks...
     console.log(months[i]); // Just prints to console
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be a shorter solution

```
var months = ["jannuary", ..., "Dezember"];

function getMonth(monthNumber){
    return months[monthNumber];
}

function getAllMonthsNames(){
    return months.join(", ");
}
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a little bit of an advanced solution however if you understand it you will learn a lot from this...

1. Create an array of months =  `var months['January','February',....]`
2. Now to get one element : **var month = months[x];**
3. To return all elements in an efficient way:

   Here we clone the months array so that we have a copy of the original

   **var clonedArray = months.clone();**

   Next we want to reverse our array so we have the last element first

   **clonedArray.reverse();**

   Next we simply pop an element at a time (pop gets the last element first that's why we reversed the array so that the first element we get with pop is January and not Decemeber

   **`while(clonedArray){` 

      `var month = clonedArray.pop();` 

      `// Do your stuff with month` 

      `$('#yourListId').append($('<li/>').html(month));` 

   `}`**

In the last line I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and it simply means... getElementById('yourListId') and add a new list item with the value of month